# Incorrect sort order custom attribute for category view

Tags: magento2.4.5p1

I'm currently writing a sort for products in category view by review rating.
I've created a custom attribute `review_rating` and sync the rating for each product into its value
[image]
[image]

And override `\Magento\Catalog\Model\Config` to add `option['rating']` to `getAttributeUsedForSortByArray()`
And override `\Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar`:

```
public function setCollection($collection)
{
    $this->_collection = $collection;

    $this->_collection->setCurPage($this->getCurrentPage());

    // we need to set pagination only if passed value integer and more that 0
    $limit = (int)$this->getLimit();
    if ($limit) {
        $this->_collection->setPageSize($limit);
    }

    if ($this->getCurrentOrder()) {
        if (($this->getCurrentOrder()) == 'rating') {
            $this->_collection->addAttributeToSort(
                'review_rating', 
                $this->getCurrentDirection()
            );
        } else if (($this->getCurrentOrder()) == 'position') {
            $this->_collection->addAttributeToSort(
                $this->getCurrentOrder(),
                $this->getCurrentDirection()
            );
            
        } else {
            $this->_collection->setOrder($this->getCurrentOrder(), $this->getCurrentDirection());
        }
    }

    return $this;
}
```

Problem:
When set page limit = 6. It seems to sort only per page
[image]
[image]

It sort correctly when I increase the page limit to contain all products
[image]

What am I missing? can anyone help? thank you